# Why am I getting this SSL error on an AWS CLI command?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

I am using the following command to get information on the machines behind my load balancer:

```
aws --region us-east-1 elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-names myLoadBalancer --output text
```

It works flawlessly when I run it from the command line, but as a cron job it gives me the following error:

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)
```

Any ideas? If it were truly a cert issue I would think I would not be able to run the command at all, but I can. It is only an issue when it is a cron job. Additionaly, I set the /etc/python/cert-verification.cfg [https] verify line to be disabled but no luck:

```
[https]
verify=disabled
```

This is how I set up my cron job:

```
sudo su -
crontab -e

#run load balancer script every fifteen minutes
*/15 * * * * /var/scripts/loadbalancerinfo.sh
```